# can't match extjs Post request on Play routes

Tags: post, extjs4, playframework-2.0

My post request looks like this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/getjson?_dc=1381814841666
Request Method:POST
```

It is generated by Extjs. And my routes is as following:

```
POST        /getjson{?_dc=<[0-9]+>para}                 controllers.Application.getjson(para:String)
```

and my controller is :

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
  def sidebar = Action {
    Ok(views.html.sidebar("SBide Bar"))
  }
  def showerr(info:String) = Action {
    Ok(views.html.showerr(info))
  }
  // how to cooperate with extjs ?
  def getjson(para:String) = Action(parse.json) { request =>  {
      val jsval: JsValue = request.body
      val w = new PrintWriter(new File("test.txt" ))
      w.write("json: %s".format(jsval.asOpt[String]))
      w.close()

      Ok("get json "+para)
    }
  }
}
```

but the server seems can't find a match for the post, it response with:

```
Action not found
For request 'POST /getjson?_dc=1381814841666'
These routes have been tried, in this order:
1 GET / controllers.Application.index
2 GET /sidebar controllers.Application.sidebar
3 GET /error/$info<.+> controllers.Application.showerr(info:String)
4 POST /getjson{?_dc=<[0-9]+>para} controllers.Application.getjson(para:String)
5 GET /assets/$file<.+> controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)
```

How should i fix it? Can anyone see what's the matter?

--EDIT

I tried the route for test:

`GET  /  test$para<%3f_dc=[0-9]+>  controllers.Application.test(para:String)`

it only worked for url like that: `/test%3f_dc=123`, not for `/test?_dc=123`. I also tried to replace `%3f` as `\?` in the regex part, it complied successfully but still can't work.

so HOW should I write the route for urls that contains a `?`  ?

--EDIT2

I changed route to the following:

`POST       /getjson$para<.*>                   controllers.Application.getjson(para:String)`

Now the route worked, but the `para` I got is empty! Most impoortant is the `request.body` is `None`! however, from chrome Audits, I can see the json is already in `Request Payload`, so WHAT I WAS MISSED ?

Answer (score 0):

This only works this way:

routes:

`POST        /getjson/$_dc<[0-9]+>                 controllers.Application.getjson(_dc:String)`

And you should call it this way:

`http://localhost:9000/getjson/1381814841666`

Unfortunately I didn't find a way to make it work with query parameters. Hope it works for you